# pass class as props in vue js?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

This is the parent component I want to send bind :class to two child component

```
 <TextInput
    :icon="['fa', 'user']"
    type="text"
    placeholder="Name"
    v-model.trim="userDetails.buyer_name.$model"
    :class="{
        'is-invalid': $v.buyer_name.$error,
        'is-valid': !$v.buyer_name.$invalid
    }"
 >
```

it's the child component here i want the to accept class as props

```
<template>
   <div class="product-form">
       <fa-icon class="icons" :icon="icon" ></fa-icon>
       <input :type="type" :placeholder="placeholder" /> 
   </div>
</template>
```

Comment: you can use inheritAttrs: false in your child component then class will automatically bind with your child component

Comment: actually want to class in the child component, I couldn't able to vuelidate  because my input field on another component

Comment: the same work I've done but it still not working

Comment: *What* is not working?  You can see the demo works so you must have done something different.  Give details:  what did you do differently?  was there an error?  etc

Comment: I took the concept from the demo, not the solution. There isn't any error,  passing props from parent to child ```:error="$v.buyer_name.$error", :isValid="!$v.buyer_name.$invalid" ```  in child copment class has initialize ``` :class="{
        'is-invalid': error,
        'is-valid': isValid
      }"```

Comment: That looks ok (assuming that comma is not there), did you also define the props in the child component?

Comment: Only other things I can think of to try are try passing `$data.$v` instead of just `$v`, and try using all lowercase props.

Answer (score 9):

You can't use the attribute `class` as a prop, because it's reserved for rendering the class of the parent element.  If you try to do that, you'll get a warning in the console:

> "class" is a reserved attribute and cannot be used as component prop.

So use another name, for example `childclass`:

```html
:childclass="{
  'is-invalid': $v.buyer_name.$error,
  'is-valid': !$v.buyer_name.$invalid
}"
```

Apply it in the child like:

```html
<input :class="childclass" />
```

Here's a demo:

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  props: ['childclass'],
  template: `
  <div>
    <input :class="childclass" />
  </div>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app"
});
```

```css
.testclass {
  border: 10px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <child :childclass="{ testclass: true }"></child>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```